# slack RTM API get channel list

Tags: node.js, api, bots, slack-api, rtm

I am using simple template of slack bot RTM API, that is given at https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk

```
var RtmClient = require('@slack/client').RtmClient;
var CLIENT_EVENTS = require('@slack/client').CLIENT_EVENTS;
var bot_token = process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN || '';
var rtm = new RtmClient(bot_token);
```

The question is how to fetch the channels name?

I found that I should use [channel.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.list) which is compatible with WEB API.

But how to call WEB API when I am using RTM API? And, in general, why all these so overcomplicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about following sample? Please import your access token, when you use this.

**Sample :**

```
var WebClient = require('@slack/client').WebClient;
var web = new WebClient('## your access token ##');
web.channels.list(function(err, info) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    for(var i in info.channels) {
      console.log("%s", info.channels[i].name, info.channels[i].id);
    }
  }
});
```

**Result :**

```
channelName1 channelID1
channelName2 channelID2
channelName3 channelID3
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, where did you find this sample?

Comment: Thank you, too. You can find some samples here. https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk/blob/0c1d59d6904528e31fbdd0fac49c1dd86ab19cb3/docs/_pages/basic_usage.md